# Django fixture in csv

Tags: python, django, csv, fixture

For a Django test I'd like to load a fixture, which is in a csv file. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django's built-in fixtures functionality doesn't support CSV. You'd need to process the file automatically using the `csv` module, probably in the test's `setUp` method.

Comment: Obviously this is many years late, but for anyone still looking for something like this, the [django-excel-fixture](https://github.com/SKisContent/django-excel-fixture) may do the trick. You can use native xlsx files.

Answer (score 1):

For easier reuse I'd suggest my [Django-PyFixture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_pyfixture/) library. You'd then program your fixture in raw python, but it would semantically look like one more fixture.